# Filepicker.io (iOS) - Cancel button only works one time

Tags: filepicker.io

I've integrated Filepicker.io into my iOS application, and while testing the upload (FPPickerDelegate) functionality I've found that I can only click the Cancel button once.  If I open the picker dialog again, further clicks on the Cancel button have no effect and I have to terminate the app to dismiss the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem came from reusing the FPController object.  I was saving it as an instance variable, and trying to reuse it each time I created a new UIPopoverController.  Recreating both at the same time solved the problem.